# Powershell Script to fetch netback client and SMTP relay

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway to fetch value for "netbackup client version" and "whether the server requires SMTP relay or not" using powershell script? Below script I used to get the citrix version in the windows server not sure how to get the other values.

```
powershell "$Citrix=(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Sort-object Name | select Name, version | Where { $_.Name -match 'Citrix'}).version -join ',';Write-Host "Citrix = $Citrix";' '"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell to get Netbackup Client Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870042/powershell-to-get-netbackup-client-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependent services can be looked up with [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet. I don't have Netback, so let's use Sql Server as an example. The Agent depends on Sql Server like so,

```
Get-Service -Name 'SQLAgent$SQLI001' -RequiredServices

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  MSSQL$SQLI001      SQL Server (SQLI001)
```

As for how to get the software version, see if the binary contains the version. This approach requires you to know the binary path. Like so,

```
(Get-ChildItem E:\MSSQL12.SQLI001\MSSQL\Binn\SQLAGENT.EXE).VersionInfo | Select-Object -Property ProductVersion,FileVersion

ProductVersion FileVersion
-------------- -----------
12.0.5207.0    2014.0120.5207.00 ((SQL14_PCU_main).170703-0132 )
```